# How to add many libraries in Qt Creator (via project file)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, point-cloud-library, libs

I have directory with many third-party libs (100 libs) and have directory with include files. How can I add all external libs in my project (in project file)?
I try that:

**Myproject.pro**

```
LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/PCL 1.9.1/lib/'

INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files/PCL 1.9.1/include'
DEPENDPATH += 'C:/Program Files/PCL 1.9.1/include'
```

but that not work for me. Through *Project->Add library-> External...* I can add just one lib and it's so long to choose every lib to add.
Also if use that:

```
LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/PCL 1.9.1/lib/' -lpcl_common_debug -lpcl_features_release -lpcl_kdtree_release...
```

It's so long, and I'm sure, should be short way to do it, like just add directory with libs and directory with include directory. Despite that simple thing, I can't find it at any.
I use qt 5.

Also, if you worked with pcl lib, I will glad to listen how to add this lib with all dependencies. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to it. Do it manually in the qmake project file after you’ve seen the pattern hinted at by the “Add Library” dialog box. The `-L` path only needs to be provided once. Then come the names of libraries with the `-l` prefix. As far as the build scripts go, it’s trivial stuff. You can begin to complain after your .pro file has more than a few hundred lines :)

I mean, let’s be serious: what’s a dozen or two `-l name` entries? It really is nothing. It should take you more time to ask such a. question than to actually add the libraries to the project.

Alternatively, use cmake, and assuming that the library has a cmake support module, it’ll all turn trivial as the module will pull in the needed dependencies. I’d advise against using qmake for any new development. It’s extremely unfortunate that Qt Creator still offers qmake templates as a default option. They have no place in anything but legacy code. Go cmake or go bust. I mean it.

Comment: Point Cloud Library does have CMake support.